# exception come fro connection to database in netbeans

Tags: java, database, swing, netbeans, odbc

whewn i try to get data from database into Jtable 
i get the following exception

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Error Code: 1045
>
> ```
> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
> ```
>
> org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Error Code: 1045
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:326)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:138)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
>       ... 45 more

however that the same code work with me on aqnother PC , i think may be the connection have problem

Answer (score 0):

The error says,

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) Error Code: 1045

This can be due to incorrect password provided to connect to the database or you dont have enough permissions to access the database. You need to check the credentials that you are using to connect to the database. or, provide grants for the machine you are trying to connect to the database. Not sure what database you are using. But i assume its MySQL from the error,

to provide grant for the user from a host, follow procedures from this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

Comment: i solved that problem by change the admin password to be root 
but then i get the following exception
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database '' Error Code: 1049

Comment: what is the database name you are using in your connection url? is it exist in the MySQL server?